# Apple Falsely Rejecting an App

Tags: app-store-connect

Apple rejected my app because of a bug that doesn't seem to reproduce on my device when deploying the binary ad-hoc.

Granted, I'm using iPhone 4s and they report it about an iPhone 5s, but the bug is about a button not clicking (specifically, Facebook login button - FBLoginView) - so I can't imagine how that would be a factor.

I am now getting an iPhone 5s to run a test on it, but even if it works - is there anything I can do about it? I've written them once and they insist they can't make it work. Is it possible they're doing something wrong? Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: If they said the button didn't work, it didn't work. You could either send the build again if you think that it could be a very occasional bug, or try and find the bug.

Comment: So it's not possible they have made a mistake? I'm doing anything I can to find this so called bug, but it works perfectly when I test it out…

Comment: I don't think that it is possible they made a mistake in reporting the bug. Well, really, it is highly improbable. It is more probable that the app crashed on that occasion. It could be something about the facebook app: I have had problems with Facebook (e.g. the fb app was in an inconsistent state or the user was not logged out and you need s/him to be logged in, or the user hasn't connected any fb account...). My recommendation is: 1. Test. Look for the possible bug as much as you can. 2. Send the app, whether you have found the bug or not (it could be others' problem, like Facebook).